# How to assign each item with the keys in map

Tags: string, list, dictionary, dart

I'm storing (non personal) data in a list of Strings which is given values by the user once an action is carried out.

Since the List is only given values once the user performs the action I don't know how many items there will be.

I'm trying to sort this List into two types of data:

`Strings` and `DateTime`

I've been trying to convert the list into a Map but I'm not sure how to assign each item with the keys "appname" and "durations". How would do you this?

Please suggest a better way of solving this issue, if there is one?

***Updated

Data example:

```
YouTube
1h 20m on screen - 2m background
1h 22m
Chrome
1h 26m on screen - 10m background
1h 36m
Google Maps
3h 4m on screen - 2h 54m background
5h 58m
```

The data is stored using a final `List<String> _usage`.

** Update: added example of what data should be parsed and how to access it.

Im looking to parse this data as json:

```
  {"app": "YouTube", "duration": "1h 22m"}, 
  //Removes the'1h 20m on screen - 2m background'

  {"app": "Chrome", "duration": "1h 36m"},
  //Removes the '1h 26m on screen - 10m background'

  {"app": "Google Maps", "duration": "5h 58m")"}
  //Removes the '3h 4m on screen - 2h 54m background'
```

I'd preferably like to access it through a Map or HashMap type.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data and how they are stored now? I am not sure I fully understand your description.

Comment: Okay I've updated it @julemand101

Comment: Thanks for the example. It is a little more complicated that I thought so can you also give an example of how you want this data to be parsed and maybe accessed? E.g. I think it is confusing what timestamp are linked to what text. It also looks like the right side of ":" can both be time and name of app? Also, it does not look like timestamps but more durations?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I've updated it with the examples you asked for. Sorry for the confusion, I mean't durations. @julemand101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could make something like this but it is difficult to make a stable solution without knowing all pitfalls in the data. E.g. I assume we always can guarantee that the name of the app comes first and then at some point some duration:

```
List<String> _usage = [
  'YouTube',
  '1h 20m on screen - 2m background',
  '1h 22m',
  'Chrome',
  '1h 26m on screen - 10m background',
  '1h 36m',
  'Google Maps',
  '3h 4m on screen - 2h 54m background',
  '5h 58m'
];

void main(List arguments) {
  final map = <String, Duration>{};

  for (var i = 0; i < _usage.length; i += 3) {
    final app = _usage[i];
    final duration = _parseDuration(_usage[i + 2]);

    if (map.containsKey(app)) {
      map[app] += duration;
    } else {
      map[app] = duration;
    }
  }

  // {YouTube: 1:22:00.000000, Chrome: 1:36:00.000000, Google Maps: 5:58:00.000000}
  print(map);
}

final _regExp = RegExp(r'(?<hours>\d+)h (?<minutes>\d+)m');
Duration _parseDuration(String line) {
  final match = _regExp.firstMatch(line);

  if (match == null) {
    throw Exception('Could not get duration from: $line');
  }

  return Duration(
      hours: int.parse(match.namedGroup('hours')),
      minutes: int.parse(match.namedGroup('minutes')));
}
```

I also added to the solution so if the same app name comes up, we add the duration instead of overwriting the previous value.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much your answer and help! Im really sorry.. I stupidly gave you the print output of the data when i edited the question. Is there any chance you could adjust the answer to accommodate  for the (actual) data? @julemand101

Comment: It OK. I have updated my solution for you updated format and also tried to clean the code a little so it is less messy.